# Wordpress Specified file failed upload test

Tags: plugin-development, php, uploads

I am trying to upload a excel file to wordpress, i am getting error:

"Specified file failed upload test.", .xls format file cannot be uploaded??

How do get arround it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the mime type to the whitelist of allowed file types.

Assuming this one still works, you can go the plugin route using.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pjw-mime-config/

Alternatively if you want to add your own mimes in code form, here's an example.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'your_custom_mimes' );
function your_custom_mimes( $mimes ) {
    $mimes['extensionhere'] = 'mimetype/goes-here';
    return $mimes;
}
```

Here's a few helpful links to help with mime types.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type
http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml